# 2x Mobile Menus - Only one opens

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I have built a basic WordPress theme which has a primary and secondary navigation. Dev site here: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/weaver/

If you narrow your screen until the mobile menu's kick in, and click on either menu, they both display the primary navigation.
How can I alter this so that the menu that is clicked shows up? Here is my jQuery:

```
;(function($) {

// DOM ready
$(function() {

    // Append the mobile icon nav
    $('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));

    // Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside
    $('.nav ul li').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i class="nav-arrow"></i></span>');

    // Click to reveal the nav
    $('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
        $('.nav-list').toggle();
    });

    // Dynamic binding to on 'click'
    $('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){

        // Toggle the nested nav
        $(this).siblings('.nav .sub-menu').toggle();

        // Toggle the arrow using CSS3 transforms
        $(this).children('.nav-arrow').toggleClass('nav-rotate');

    });

});
```

})(jQuery);

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing this piece of JS:

```
// Click to reveal the nav
$('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
    //$('.nav-list').toggle();
    $(this).parent().children(".nav-list").toggle();
});
```